# How to use Visual Studio with CMake AND preserve file structure

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake

I use CMake to create C++ projects. Then I would like to use Visual Studio as my IDE. But the issue I face is that I can't get files to be structured properly.
Here is the problem:

Let's assume I have the following [file structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WWWb4.png) on the disk.

And here is my CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20)

set(sourceDirectory   src)
set(includeDirectory  include)
set(targetName        vulkan-tutorial)
set(targetVersion     1.0.0)

project(${targetName} VERSION ${targetVersion})

file(GLOB src
  ${sourceDirectory}/*.cpp
  ${sourceDirectory}/**/*.cpp
  ${sourceDirectory}/**/**/*.cpp
)

add_executable(${targetName} ${src})

target_include_directories(${targetName} PRIVATE ${includeDirectory})
```

Here is [what this project looks like in Visual Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q1nHM.png) with filters.
Or [without using VS-filters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BTbyP.png).

I can create new files, but they're not going to land, where I want them to. The behavior I want to achieve is extremely simple: I want to see the root directory of my project and its "src" and "include" folders. I want to be able to right-click them and create new folders and files. Then I want Visual Studio to create them inside the selected folder. Like it would be in every normal file-explorer.

One solution I could imagine is to generate project files not inside a "build folder", but in the root directory of the project itself, which is obviously a terrible solution and leads to a pollution of the project structure.

Summarized - here is the [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gWFfJ.png) I want to end up with (now I can achieve it only by generating the project in the root). But all the build files should be located in the corresponding "build" folder in the root of the project.

I also would like to add that I tried to use different functions for CMake that kind of group my files together, but I just ended up with lots of filters that reflect my project structure on the disk. Of course, I still wasn't able to add new folders and files dynamically.

I appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use the `Open Folder` option in visual studio.

This will open the directory and automatically configure the project using CMake. It will display the tree independently from the CMake configuration structure.

Microsoft has a page [CMake projects in Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/cmake-projects-in-visual-studio?view=msvc-160), that explains how to properly import CMake projects in visual studio

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot! Exactly what I was looking for!